# How can I align HTML elements printed in a loop?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm printing a loop dynamically in a col-3. Each column contains 4 HTML elements.

1. An Image
2. A Title
3. Some text content
4. A button

Is it possible to make each elements top, line up with each other regardless of how many lines the element on top is?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <h2 class="pb-4">Title1</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h2 class="pb-4">Title2</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h2 class="pb-4">Title3</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <h2 class="pb-4">Title <br> 4</h2>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a [mre] within the question here on Stack Overflow, rather than only on an external site.

Comment: Can you change your markup? It sounds like you're looking for a table layout.

Comment: if it was to be in a table what would be in the <li> tags?  would each column be its own separate table?

Comment: @jermaynewilliams So in your example, is the problem that the fourth column content is too low?

Comment: <h2 class="pb-4">Title 4</h2> remove <br>. It is causing the error.

Comment: @Alex Yes thats my problem. in my application I have titles that end up exceeding the limit of the column and wrapping (as it should). so Im trying to align all of my text beneath it to to be at the same height regardless of title size.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Yes In this example it is. its just to show my point of a title with 2 lines instead of 1

Comment: @jermaynewilliams Instead of having one row, with multiple columns each containing all of that stuff, I would have one row for each of the title, image, button, etc, and then split each row into four columns, and fill them with the content.

Comment: You would need to find the maximum height for each of the tags image, title, p, button. From there you could.

Comment: @Alex Did you mean like this? I put it in a codepen because I dont think I can snippet in comments.
https://codepen.io/JWILLZ/pen/QWLEoxZ?editors=1010

Comment: @arundeepchohan the reason Im trying to avoid that way is because I dont think its the most responsive. If I can't find a different way I will write media queries and try that

Comment: @jermaynewilliams you are doing things in the right way just remove the <br> tag

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would split the content into various rows, and put the columns inside those rows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row" id="titles_row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <h2 class="pb-4">Title1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <h2 class="pb-4">Title2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <h2 class="pb-4">Title3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <h2 class="pb-4">Title <br> 4</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="texts_row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to separate your `<h3>` and `<p>` into separate rows. That allows them to all be aligned horizontally.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h2 class="pb-4">Title1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h2 class="pb-4">Title2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h2 class="pb-4">Title3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h2 class="pb-4">Title <br> 4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
      <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```